# C# : New-SelfSignedCertificate powershell cmdlet is not working using new app domain

Tags: powershell

I am trying to execute below code by creating new appdomain and it seems not working. New entry in the certlm.msc is not getting created. Please refer screenshot attached. [CertLM][1]

If I use current domain then it works as expected.

I am using Windows 10. Also tried passing CurrentDomain evidence and other details, but no luck. Properties of new domain and current domain looks fine to me. Also used process explorer and it seems Microsoft.CertificateServices.PKIClient.Cmdlets.dll loaded properly in both the cases.

```
**EXE code:**

 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Running powershell script");            

            InitialSessionState iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();       

            using (System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Runspace space = System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(iss))
            {
                space.Open();

                using (System.Management.Automation.PowerShell shell = System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Create())
                {
                    string sScriptContent = "New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName localhost -CertStoreLocation \"cert:\\LocalMachine\\My\"";

                    shell.Runspace = space;    

                    shell.AddScript(sScriptContent, true);

                   IAsyncResult result = shell.BeginInvoke();

                   WaitHandle[] wait = { result.AsyncWaitHandle };
                  WaitHandle.WaitAny(wait);
                }

                space.Close();
            }
        }

    }

**Sample application that calls above EXE**

public class Class1
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /* Not Working.*/
            System.AppDomain newDomain = System.AppDomain.CreateDomain("NewApplicationDomain");
            newDomain.ExecuteAssembly("PowerShellCertificateTest.exe");

            //Unload the application domain:
            System.AppDomain.Unload(newDomain);

            // Working using current domain...
            System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ExecuteAssembly("PowerShellCertificateTest.exe");

           Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzCz0.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting below config option *useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy* solved the issue. But still trying to figure out how CurrentDomain is working with out this config setting.

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
```